# Crop image during the Animation, Set to image View

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

working on Some animation with imageView.

At Starting width of my imageView would be 700 px(size of image is 700*300).
Now I have to reduce the imageView width to 0 px with animation.
Duration of animation is 1 hr.

Say after 30min the width of my imageView would be 350 Px.

As I am using the same image(700*300)in imageView having only 350 px Width,the image in imageView is  looks shrinking in animation.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:3600];
newRect.size.width = 0;
imgView.frame = newRect;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

So during the animation I want to crop the image to the size of imageView. 
How can I achieve this. Is there any way to do changes for image in between AnimationTime.

Any Help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try reverse scenario. To create animation while cropping the image? You would schedule timer at every 0.5 seconds and you will crop image piece by piece and then show cropped image in imageView. Then you will achieve smooth animation, and cropped image.